# Installing Pandas v.0.24.2 with pip2 on Ubuntu 16.04 gives numpy error

Tags: pandas, python-2.7, numpy, ubuntu-16.04

I'm trying to install the package `pandas` version 0.24.2 with pip2. It seems to work find until it reaches the `numpy` part. I already have `numpy` v. 1.16.5 installed. The reason I'm using older versions is that I am working with ROS Kinetic which doesn't support Python3. Though Python3 is already installed with my Ubuntu 16.04.

So my question is how do I install `pandas` version 0.24.2 and avoid the error below.

```
$ pip2 install pandas==0.24.2

Collecting pandas==0.24.2
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/db/83/7d4008ffc2988066ff37f6a0bb6d7b60822367dcb36ba5e39aa7801fda54/pandas-0.24.2-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Collecting python-dateutil>=2.5.0 (from pandas==0.24.2)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d4/70/d60450c3dd48ef87586924207ae8907090de0b306af2bce5d134d78615cb/python_dateutil-2.8.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl
Collecting numpy>=1.12.0 (from pandas==0.24.2)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/84/1e/ff467ac56bfeaea51d4a2e72d315c1fe440b20192fea7e460f0f248acac8/numpy-1.18.2.zip
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-build-LpE1lF/numpy/setup.py", line 32, in <module>
        raise RuntimeError("Python version >= 3.5 required.")
    RuntimeError: Python version >= 3.5 required.

    ----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-LpE1lF/numpy/
```

Comment: I have the same problem